# Hibernate - initialize multiple collections in one query

Tags: hibernate

I have an `Order` entity with collection `List<OrderItem> items`. I need a procedure which loads items for multiple already loaded orders in one query (`from Item where order in (:orders)`)

I know there is possibility to fetch orders with items (join fetch, entity graph, ...), but I want to fetch items in separate query.

### One working solution

I created `ItemReposiotory` with method `findAllByOrderIn(Iterable<Order> orders)`. I call this repository method, group results by `Item::order` and set created lists to particular orders.

#### problems:

- I think this solution is just workaround and could have some side effects as I initialized collections "programatically" and I went around hibernate.
- This solution is not working if items collection is marked `orphanRemoval = true` with exception `A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@FetchMode( SUBSELECT )` which will lazily initialize all collections with a single query.

Comment: Thank you for good solution, nevertheless in my procedure I'm looking for possibility to fetch items from sub-select of originally loaded orders.